# Redirect problem with parameterized URLs in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, redirect, query-string

I have a few 404 page indexing issues to solve within my wordpress website. No plugin was able to solve my problems. So I've searched all the internet on how to redirect in .htaccess but no solution found as yet. I really hope now, that you guys can help.

Here are 3 samples of URLs (no clue where they come from) that I tried to redirect in different ways and this would be the simple 301 redirect in htaccess (RewriteEngine On -> place on top of my file):

1. Redirect 301 /de/bitcoin-hardware-wallet-kaufberatung?page=m1xdLGgMRvZhG1Rn&cox=1659941919&cost=fco5WU1eo7xSx6BV&cox=b5sggfQikseKfNp6&utm=guang5/ https://example.com/de/bitcoin-hardware-wallet-kaufberatung/
2. Redirect 301 /bitcoin-hardware-wallet?order=e5625e61-2799-484a-aaf1-7b19675d7142&rsv_bp=MxleF0G7pzrG2rcH&peo=MTy4npgwHEw12esB&num=88fe7eac-34e4-465f-9604-46f311df76c4&page=0.7340593690012602&utm=guang5 https://example.com/bitcoin-hardware-wallet/
3. Redirect 301 /de/?p=18679 https://example.com/de/

I have also tried different RewriteConditions using Query String rules but no luck so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the above. I've also tried different RewriteRules found here with RewriteConditions using Query Strins but no luck so far. I just want to get rid of the 404 errors and redirect properly.